# Weird behavior when scrolling StaggeredGridLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, staggered-gridview

I have a RecyclerView to show some images loaded by Picasso. As they have different aspect ratios, I'm using a StaggeredGridLayoutManager. Everything looks good, but when scrolling and a new image shows up, images move up or down a little, like they are getting been relocated. They dont stay in the same place.

The thing is, if I use a GridLayout, everything works perfectly, looks like having different item's sizes messes it up.

This is the ActivityMain class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Especificamos el layout 'products_grid.xml'
        setContentView(R.layout.products_grid);

        _initData();
        _initAuxViews();
        _initToolbar();
        _initNavigationDrawers();
        _initAnimations();

        new ConnectToServer().execute();
    }



protected void _initRecyclerView()
{   
    mProductsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.grid_recycler);
    mStaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mProductAdapter = new ProductsGridAdapter(this, mProductsDisplayedList);

    mProductsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mStaggeredGridLayoutManager);
    mProductsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);
    mProductsRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
            {
               ...
            }
}
```

main.xml, I have a custom RecyclerView, but this does not affect, I checked it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shop_background_bw">

        <!-- Contenido principal -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- Recylcer Grid -->
            <com.wallakoala.wallakoala.Views.GridRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/grid_recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layoutAnimation="@anim/grid_layout_animation"/>

            <!-- Toolbar -->
            <include android:id="@+id/appbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar">

            </include>

            <!-- Loading View -->
            <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
                android:id="@+id/avloadingIndicatorView"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:indicator="BallClipRotate"
                app:indicator_color="@color/colorAccent"/>

            <!-- Texto de no prductos -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nodata_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/action_bar_height"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/action_bar_height"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/nodata_message"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/left_navigation_drawer"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

item_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Loading View -->
        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/avloadingitem"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:indicator="BallClipRotate"
            app:indicator_color="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <!-- Background-->
        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/grid_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/colorText"
            android:alpha="0.2"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:riv_corner_radius_bottom_left="4dp"
            app:riv_corner_radius_bottom_right="4dp"
            app:riv_corner_radius_top_left="4dp"
            app:riv_corner_radius_top_right="4dp"/>

        <!-- Main Image-->
        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/grid_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:riv_corner_radius_bottom_left="4dp"
            app:riv_corner_radius_bottom_right="4dp"
            app:riv_corner_radius_top_left="4dp"
            app:riv_corner_radius_top_right="4dp"/>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:alpha="0.75">

            <!-- Info extra -->
            <include android:id="@+id/extraInfo"
                layout="@layout/product_footer_extra"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

            <!-- Info principal -->
            <include android:id="@+id/mainFooter"
                layout="@layout/product_footer"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/footer_height"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/extraInfo"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

EDIT: Adapter code:

```
public class ProductsGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsGridAdapter.ProductHolder>
{
    /* Constants */
    private static final String TAG = "CUOKA";
    private static final String PACKAGE = "com.wallakoala.wallakoala";

    /* Context */
    private static Context mContext;

    /* Data */
    private static List<Product> mProductList;

    public static class ProductHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        private Product mProduct;

        private ImageButton mFavImageButton;
        private ImageView mProductImageView;
        private ImageView mErrorImageView;
        private View mLoadingView;
        private View mBackgroundView;
        private View mProductFooterView, mProductFooterExtraView, mProductFooterMainView;
        private TextView mTitleTextView, mSubtitleTextView, mNameTextView, mPriceTextView;

        private Animation scaleUpFooterExtra, scaleDownFooterExtra;

        public ProductHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            mErrorImageView   = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.broken_image);
            mTitleTextView    = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.footer_title);
            mSubtitleTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.footer_subtitle);
            mProductImageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            mFavImageButton   = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.footer_fav_button);
            mNameTextView     = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            mPriceTextView    = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);

            mBackgroundView         = itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_background);
            mLoadingView            = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avloadingitem);
            mProductFooterView      = itemView.findViewById(R.id.footer);
            mProductFooterExtraView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.extraInfo);
            mProductFooterMainView  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainFooter);

            mProductFooterView.setOnClickListener(this);
            //mProductImageView.setOnClickListener(this);

            scaleUpFooterExtra = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.scale_up);
            scaleDownFooterExtra = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.scale_down);
        }

        public void bindProduct(Product product)
        {
            /* Inicializamos los TextViews */
            mTitleTextView.setText(product.getShop());
            mSubtitleTextView.setText(product.getColors().get(0).getReference());
            mNameTextView.setText(product.getName());
            mPriceTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", product.getPrice()) + "€");

            /* Ocultamos la info, IMPORTANTE. Cosas malas pasan si no se pone. Tambien la imagen de error. */
            mProductFooterExtraView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mProductFooterMainView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mErrorImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            /* Mostramos la view de carga y el background */
            mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mBackgroundView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            /* Ponemos el icono del corazon. */
            mFavImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_white);

            /* Cargamos la imagen usando Picasso */
            String url = product.getColors().get(0).getImages().get(0).getPath().replaceAll(".jpg", "_Small.jpg");
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                   .load(url)
                   .into(mProductImageView, new Callback() {
                       @Override
                       public void onSuccess() {
                           mBackgroundView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           mProductFooterMainView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onError() {
                           mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           mErrorImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       }
                   });

            mProduct = product;
        }

    public ProductsGridAdapter(Context context, List<Product> productList)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mProductList = productList;
    }

    public void updateProductList(List<Product> productList)
    {
        mProductList = productList;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                                      .inflate(R.layout.product_item_grid
                                                    , viewGroup
                                                    , false );

        return new ProductHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductHolder productHolder, int pos)
    {
        productHolder.bindProduct(mProductList.get(pos));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return mProductList.size();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**: I've found out what's going on. The cardview is firstly created without the image, when it's loaded, the layout is redrawn, therefore the weird movement produced. I tried to do this:

WHen the image is first loaded, I save the height of it, and when the recyclerView is scrolled up, I set the background image of the cardview with the height already saved so it has the same dimensions as the image, and this should do the trick. But it doesnt. This is what I tried, this code belongs to the Holder constructor in the Adapter.

```
        final ViewTreeObserver mProductImageViewTreeObserver = mProductImageView.getViewTreeObserver();
        final ViewTreeObserver mBackgroundTreeObserver = mBackgroundView.getViewTreeObserver();
        mProductImageViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                if (mProductHeight != mProductImageView.getHeight())
                {
                    mProductHeight = mProductImageView.getHeight();
                }
            }
        });

        mBackgroundTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw()
            {
                if((mProductHeight > 0) && (mProductHeight != mBackgroundView.getHeight()))
                {
                    mBackgroundView.getLayoutParams().height = mProductHeight;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Does anyone have a clue of what's wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could kindly you post your ProductsGridAdapter?

Comment: Question edited with the code

Comment: I noticed that the problem is as, the image is not loaded, Android draws the cardview with the other views. Once the image is loaded, it draws again, therefore the movement produced. Please, see the edit for possible approach

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. The trick is to save the aspect ratio when loading the image for the first time into a Target object.

Then, in the OnPrepareLoad, check if this image has been loaded previously. If so, use the aspect ratio stored to set the final height, this way, there's no readjustment and the scroll works smoothly.

```
mTarget = new Target()
        {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
            {
                mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mProductFooterMainView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mProductImageView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                mProductImageView.setBackgroundColor(-1);
                mProductImageView.setAlpha(1.0f);


                if (mProductBitmapArray[position] == 0.0f)
                    mProductBitmapArray[position] = (double)bitmap.getHeight() / (double)bitmap.getWidth();

                mProductImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable)
            {
                ... do stuff
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable)
            {
                mProductImageView.setImageBitmap(null);

                if (mProductBitmapArray[position] != 0)
                    mProductImageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(mProductImageView.getWidth()
                                                                            * mProductBitmapArray[position]);
                else
                    mProductImageView.getLayoutParams().height = 600;

                mProductImageView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorText));
                mProductImageView.setAlpha(0.1f);
            }
        };
```